# Getting pointer to registered QML type

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtcore

If i have type registered

```
qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("com.sample.myclass", 1, 0, "myClass");
```

and i want to get pointer to registered type i.e,

```
MyClass* registeredClass = **getQmlRegisteredType<MyClass>(1, 0)**;
```

Is it even possible? Reason why i want it because i want to set some properties of same object at certain time so that when qml looks at it, it knows. The other reason is i want to set context property so that i do not have to do:

```
MyClass {
    id: cls
}
....
cls.someMethod
```

I will just do

```
((QQmlContext*)viewer.rootContext())->setContextProperty("cls", 
    (QObject*)pointerToMyClass); // Pardon my C style cast
```

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your explanation. You mean, you do not have access to the registered class at some point where you would like to use it?

Comment: At C++ level, or is it that I am understanding `qmlRegisterType` wrong? My understanding is that QML engine constructs and registers class into memory and pass on reference to QML. If this is the case, all I want is same reference that is passed on to QML, in C++ side.

Comment: Ah, got it. You are looking for findChildren and objectName.

Comment: But `viewer.findChild<MyClass*>("myClass")` returns nullptr

Comment: Of course, you need to have this: `objectName: "myClass"` inside your MyClass qml declaration, but then again, MyClass is a C++ class, so you could pass access from C++ to C++ without involing QML.

Comment: is there a way to skip MyClass qml declaration or is it necessary? Can i declare it on C++ side and access object name from QML? Is my understanding correct as per my previous comment?

Comment: You could set the context property from C++ side, and then you would have access to that object from C++ directly, but as a quickfix, you could do the objectName "trick", too. Does that work as you want it to?

Comment: Ok so (for quick test) i declared `MyClass` in QML side and set it's `objectName` prop and tried setting context prop from cpp side and it's still returning me nullptr

Comment: I can do what i want by just `((QQmlContext*)viewer.rootContext())->setContextProperty("cls", 
    (QObject*)new MyClass());` but thats waste of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally not declare the class in QML directory. I would expose an object instance from C++ via the context propety system, and then you could also have access to that object on the C++ side, no matter what you wish to do with it.

This is some pseudo-code that I would write if I were you:

```
MyClass myClass;
QQmlContext *ctxt = view->rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myClass", &myClass);
```

Note that all the casts you are doing is unnecessary. Having this done, you could have access to the "myClass" instance. You could pass it on to other parts of the code base if needed.

Comment: I used `CLOG_AFTER_N` to find out if `viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cls", (QObject*)new MyClass());` constructs twice, and it does not so I am good. Thanks for your help :) Marked your question as answer as I would be doing something similar but singleton pattern. Thanks